# Same folder structure as solution folder structure VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, architecture, visual-studio-2019

I'm looking for a way to have my folder structure to be the same as the one in my solution.

Something similar to what I'm looking for can be seen here: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

The question is how can I achieve the src/tests folders separation in both Solution and Windows Explorer without using any predefined template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

- create src and test folders in the main folder where your solution is stored
- open your solution with visual studio
- right-click on solution -> add -> new solution folder

  - rename in src
  - rename in test
- right-click on folder -> add -> existing project (or new project if it doesn't exist)
  and that's all.
  In this way, you will be able to see src and test folders separated in both solution and explorer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, shame on me, because initially I did the same but when I created the new project I forgot to change the location, so I ended up with new project in the root folder instead of inside the src folder in explorer

Comment: You're welcome, but if you accidentally create the project in the wrong folder remember that you can always remove project from your solution, move it in the folder you desire and re-add it to de solution.
But remember to change also the namespace, that probably is relative to the folder in which it was at the moment of the creation